# BufferedReader returns file that does not match the original

Tags: java, file, javafx, bufferedreader

I am using a BufferedReader to read a file and store each line in a String ArrayList. However, after running the BufferedReader, reading the file, storing it, and printing the ArrayList, I get something different from the original file.

My code to read file:

```
    public File shooterUIFile = new File("./src/com/xyfurion/hudedit/bin/resources/ShooterUI.ini");
    public ArrayList<String> shooterUIRead = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> shooterUIWrote = new ArrayList<>();
    public void readHUDFile(){
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(shooterUIFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null)
                shooterUIRead.add(bufferedReader.readLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < shooterUIRead.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(shooterUIRead.get(i));

            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + shooterUIFile + "'");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + shooterUIFile + "'");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output (File printed): [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/qdt3u06A)

Original File: [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/VnaUH6d9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only keeping every other line , since you are calling `readLine` twice each iteration and discarding the first read line (the one in the `while` condition).

You may avoid it this way :

```
    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        shooterUIRead.add(line);
```